# Determining coefficients to a nonhomogenous differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-series

Consider the following ODE:

$$\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2} + kx = f(t)$$

where $$f(t) = \frac{1}{2} +\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{ \frac{-4}{n \pi} \sin\left(\frac{n \pi t}{2}\right)}$$ was derived using fourier series.

I have to find a particular solution. The sum symbol confuses me on this one but I will treat it as one does normally when looking to find a particular solution.

**My thoughts:**

Guess the solution: 
$$ x(t) = A_1 t+ A_0 + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{ B \sin\left(\frac{n \pi t}{2}\right) + C \cos\left(\frac{n \pi t}{2}\right)} $$

After taking the second derivative and matching coefficients I arrive to the conclusion that the coefficients of the particular solution are:

$$ A_1 = 0 $$

$$ A_0 = \frac{1}{2k} $$

$$ C = 0 $$

$$ B = - \frac{4}{(k - m (\frac{n \pi}{2})^2)n \pi} $$

Should I take into consideration the sum operator when determining the coefficient $B$,

$$ B = - \frac{ \frac{4b}{ \pi } \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n}} }{a - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{( \frac{n \pi}{2})^2}} $$

where $$a = \frac{k}{m}, \space b = \frac{1}{m}$$

and insert this with the sum operator (as a second sum) into my guess?